# How to bind for loop data to An Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, angular2-forms

Here I'm trying to loop through my data but how can I bind this loop data to an Array?

```
 var ArrayData = this.Volunter[0];
```

Here I bind my data to ArrayData and I loop through this data

```
for (var i = 0; i < ArrayData.length; i++) {
    var AmtContrybuted = ArrayData[i].AmountContr
    var YearDedClaim = ArrayData[i].AmountContr;
    var AllowableYears = ArrayData[i].AllowableYear;
    if (YearDedClaim < AllowableYears) {
        var AmtElegible =AmtContrybuted/AllowableYears
    } else {
        ArrayData[i].amounteligible == 0;
    }
}
```

How can I bind this data to an ArrayData?

Comment: Will be `==` in `ArrayData[i].amounteligible == 0;` ?
It is not an assignment, rather it is just checking the equality without any operation following.

Comment: @HarunurRashid could u please update complete Coe

Comment: @HarunurRashid is saying that you might have a typo. Try using `=` instead of `==` for line 8 of the above code

Comment: @Felipe , yes. You are right :)